# Is char* created with "..." and new are on stack and heap respectively? Just want a brief answer if my understanding is right or wrong?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, string-literals, storage-duration

```
const char* s1 = "John";
const char* s2 = new char[] {"Cena"};
// is s1 on stack?
// is s2 on heap?
...
// use s1 and s2
...

delete s1;
// do I need to delete s1?

delete[] s2?
// s2 definitely must be deleted right?
```

I have added my questions in the comments above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `s1` is a pointer and is initialized with the address of a `const char[5]` which is allocated in the constant data segment. Of course, you are not allowed to `delete s1`. The rule is actually quite simple: `delete` what you `new` and `delete[]` what you `new[]` (no more or less).

Comment: One more thing, when I delete a `char*` created by `new` using `delete[] s2` works and using `delete s2` also works. Is it the way it is or why is that?

Comment: @hklsb If you use `new[]` you should `delete[]`. Using `delete` makes the program have undefined behavior.

Comment: Again, see above. To `delete` which was created with `new[]` (or vice versa) is Undefined Behavior. It may work accidentally, or it even may seem to work only.

Comment: Thanks a lot. helps me a lot in my learning journey. I'm on my own.

Comment: One more note: Things become complicated if you don't know whether a `const char* s` points to something which is either assigned the address of a constant string literal or something created with `new char[]`. This should be prevented at all as it results either in memory leaks (not deleting at all) or Undefined Behavior (deleting things which are not created by new). The only resort is a clear ownership management where the author is responsible for. To your luck, `new`/`new[]` and `delete`/`delete[]` are actually not necessary anymore. The standard library is full of safer replacements...

Comment: ...like e.g. `std::string`.

Comment: To address the title Q: `s1` is neither on the stack nor in the heap -- it is _likely_ in a read-only global memory segment belonging to your program.

Comment: Strange things happened too. e.g after I delete s2 with `delete` or `delete[] ` it's not gone in debugging. I see afterwards `s2` got random values and then got other values again. Sorry for not showing it it's simple after `delete s2` I just create a couple more `char* ` string with `new`.

Comment: Slight refinement: `s1` and `s2` are both automatic variables and probably on the stack. What they point at is an entirely different matter.

Comment: To save time, the memory used by an object is rarely reclaimed immediately after it is `delete`ed` and can often still be available. Allocation and deallocation of memory takes time and the program might need that memory again later, so why give it back before you have to? Consider `delete` to only be a promise that you won't use it again and that the system can take the memory back or reuse it at any time. Because it lingers, yes you may be able to keep observing it, but doing so breaks the promise and literally anything could happen.

Comment: My God, I wanted for simple thing but rather found a rabbit hole I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may delete what was created using the operator new.

String literals have static storage duration. They are alive until the program ends.

In this code snippet

```
const char* s1 = "John";
const char* s2 = new char[] {"Cena"};
```

there is allocated dynamically only the array initialized by the string literal `"Cena"`. So to delete it (to free the allocated memory) you need apply the operator delete [] to the pointer `s2`.

```
delete [] s2;
```

Comment: So basically s1 is on stack and s2 is on heap, right?

Comment: @hklsb s1 and s2 are either in stack (that is having automatic storage duration) or in a namespace (having static storage duration).  And the pointer s2  points to a dynamically allocated memory (array) in the heap.

Comment: Very interesting. BTW thanks for helping me out, glad that there are still good people who want to support others still struggling like me.

Comment: @hklsb Remember that pointers are objects too. When you say `s1` you are referring to the pointer, not the pointed object. Both pointers `s1` and `s2` are function local objects (assuming this code is in a function), which is "on the stack" (though "on the stack" is not c++ terminology). What `s1` points to has static storage duration, it isn't "on the stack" as its lifetime is not related to the function scope. What `s2` points to has dynamic storage duration it is also not "on the stack" because its lifetime is also not related to the function scope.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux So the thing s1 pointed to is not on stack, but the thing s2 pointed to is on heap (free store) right?

Comment: @hklsb s1 points to string literal that has static storage duration. s2 points to the first element of a dynamically allocated array in heap.

Comment: @hklsb Yes, neither pointed object is "on the stack". Yes, the object pointed to by `s2` uses storage from free store.